# Worthy bipedal challenger for dominant species of large frogs possessing medieval technology

Tags: science-fiction, fauna, bronze-age

I'm looking for a bit of inspiration to help me with a bit of writer's block I've got going on at the moment.

In my novel, "A Tale of Galaxies", every being is bipedal due to various peculiarities of the cultural and religious context of the world Bargon 7. Frogs (which are five times the size of the kind we get on Earth and are extremely muscly) are the apex species, with reasonably advanced technology (Bronze Age equivalent).

Given this backdrop, a class of frog warrior priests has risen to prominence and taken control of the central council of Celirion 9. There are various other creatures which we have on Earth. but everything is bipedal.  These are normal size and haven't evolved any differently, but I haven't fancied any of these to be good challengers for the frogs.

Which other animals from real life could I adapt to stand on two feet and be a relatively equal challenge to the frogs?

Comment: Are you looking for 'hard counter' or 'soft counter' - i.e. an enemy which has innate qualities which shut down the frogs, or an enemy that can give a reasonable battle against them?

Comment: ...large storks.

Comment: @Halfthawed an enemy which can give reasonable battle against them

Comment: Out of curiosity and for context, how did a bunch of warrior priests with bronze age tech get from Bargon 7 to the planet Celerion 9, it seems that there's a huge chunk of your question missing - or rather the context you provide is barely relevant to the question. The question seems to ask for suggestions from an infinite variety of possibilities - that would be off topic here. You'd need to narrow down what's acceptable and appropriate in your worlds. I'm voting to put on-hold as unclear so you can clear-up the issues.

Comment: Second clarification question - bronze age and medieval age technology are two different things entirely. Which one is it?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking.  Is the base animal required to be of a similar size to the base stock?   Because it seems like a bear, or a rhino, or an elephant, or a lion, or a <insert any of a number of animals that are all larger and more powerful than even a 5x frog>, would all easily deal with a large frog.

Comment: Hi J. Campbell, welcome to Worldbuilding officially! We're glad you came out of the lurking shadows to put forward an interesting question. Sadly, Worldbuilding isn't great at providing inspiration for problems like writer's block because we're much better at answering specific questions than we are at idea-generation. I've voted to place your question on hold until you get a chance to [edit] and provide some more direction to answerers, specifically what you're hoping an excellent answer would look like.

Comment: Are the opposition also bronze aged, or are you looking for a more primitive counterpart?

Answer (score 5):

...Large storks.

In fable, fiction, and fact, the natural enemy of the frog is the stork.

See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Frogs_Who_Desired_a_King

Comment: That's only because of relative size. If the stork and the frog were the same size, storks wouldn't have an advantage.

Comment: These are *bronze age* frogs. The storks could easily be as advanced as the frogs in the kind of weaponry -- pilae, pikes, bows, ballistae -- that multiplies the force of warriors of any size.

Answer (score 3):

There are many possible choices.  But the one that comes to mind is:

### Bunnies!

I'm using the term "bunnies" very generically to mean either rabbits or hares (even though technically bunnies are baby rabbits; give me some creative license here).  [European Hares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_hare) are known for "boxing."

[image]

Increase their size to match the frogs and make them fully bipedal.  They already have strong legs like frogs do.  Both have useful arms and voice boxes.  Frogs do best in water and require access to it. Bunnies can deal with water to a degree but live outside it.

Most bunnies are usually fairly docile and calm but can fight when the need arises.  They would make excellent warriors or resistance fighters.  They could work alongside the frogs or be a competing force.  Whatever your story requires.

Comment: that remind me of this 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch%C5%8Dj%C5%AB-jinbutsu-giga

Comment: @LiJun That's a great link.  It might be a start to a good answer.